# Authorization Code: Is there a specific format it has to follow?

Tags: oauth2

I am currently digging into OAuth 2.0 and especially the authorization code grant. What I couldn't find from within RFC6749 is if the authorization code has to follow a specific format.

The RFC says that "[...] Authorization codes operate as plaintext bearer credentials". Does that mean it is up to the authorization server to what *form* it takes? I mean is it just a random string that can be considered a one-time-password?

Comment: To my knowledge, which you should consider hearsay and not gospel, OAuth 2.0 does not follow a specific format, which makes interoperability a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the authorization server you issue the code, and as the authorization server you receive the code and exchange it for the requested token. The caller treats it as an opaque value. They receive it from the authorization server, and then forward it to the authorization server to get the token they asked for.

As such, the format is up to you. Generally folks often use a random key that refers to something in a database, kinda sorta similar to a session key. Others encrypt a blob containing the token itself.

The only real requirements are that it isn't guessable, doesn't leak the token, and can't be replayed.